# How can I generate a JaCoCo XML report for Sonarcloud in a project using apache commons-parent?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco

i'm working on a project and the pom.xml file is a child of apache commons-parent (commons-parent provides common settings for all Apache Commons components). I have to calculate code coverage using JaCoCo and Sonarcloud, but to do so I need the jacoco report to be an xml file, while unfortunately the plugin used in commons-parent outputs a .exec file.
How can I do this?

I tried overriding the jacoco plugin but it still used the parent configuration.

EDIT: Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76328519/14591080), I realized I was actually trying to add coverage for a single-module maven project when it actually was a multi-module.

Comment: Please show how you have tried to overwrite the parent configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an example repository to share? The key point is to determine if you have a single-module or multi-module Maven project and then you can design the report or report-aggregate goal of the [jacoco-maven-plugin](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html).

Here are some links to help:

- Sample Maven repos with Jacoco coverage: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples
- Importing Jacoco coverage using XML format: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/coverage-test-data-importing-jacoco-coverage-report-in-xml-format/12151

For more help, you should ask your question in [Sonar Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/) where the official Sonar employees reside to help.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. The repository is [this one](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/). The thing i tried to "override" it is adding the profile reported in the third link you posted, and tried `mvn verify sonar:sonar`, but it still outputs a jacoco.exec file

Comment: Do you have a link to what pom.xml settings you are using?

Comment: The repository you linked leads to this repo: https://github.com/apache/commons-cli, which is a single module Maven project. You can find how to calculate coverage from this project here: https://github.com/apache/commons-cli/blob/master/.github/workflows/coverage.yml#LL47C19-L47C39

So you can run it in separate steps or as one step like `mvn clean test jacoco:report verify -ntp sonar:sonar`